# Column is not the same data type as referencing column

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints, alter-table

I'm altering table to add a foreign key as following:

```
ALTER TABLE [MS_Test].[dbo].[Studies]
   ADD CONSTRAINT F_Id
       FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES [M_Test].[dbo].[MS](Id);
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Column 'MS_Test.dbo.FM.Id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Studies.Id' in foreign key 'F_Id'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I have already a lot of data stored in my tables so I can't just drop table and create it again.

Comment: Isn't the error clear?  The data type of `Id` has to match the data type of `[M_Test].[dbo].[MS](Id)`.

Comment: I can't just change the data type as it is a foregin key in another table as well

Comment: I do not understand how can a table's `id` reference another table's `id`?

Comment: What *are* the datatypes involved?

Comment: Studies table has PK that is uniqueidentifier. MS table has Id as PK and it is an int, I need to add "Id" column to Studies table

Comment: The thing is I alread have a column called Id in Studies table

Comment: Then add it as `MS_id`...

Answer (score 1):

SQL has the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER COLUMN [column] SET DATA TYPE [new data type]
```

### EDIT

As you modified the question, it seems that you need to add a new column, instead of changing an existing one.

Try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [MS_Test].[dbo].[Studies]
  ADD COLUMN MS_id {your [MS_Test].[dbo].[MS].Id column type};
ALTER TABLE [MS_Test].[dbo].[Studies]
  ADD CONSTRAINT F_Id
    FOREIGN KEY (MS_id) REFERENCES [M_Test].[dbo].[MS](Id);
```

Comment: This question is about **SQL Server** - this code doesn't work for SQL Server / T-SQL

Comment: When i wrote this answer, no `SQL-Server` tag was present, just `SQL`...

Comment: But it is correct that I need to add a new column to the table

Comment: What type is your `[MS_Test].[dbo].[MS].Id` column?